# Multiple images on one page of carousel with event fire

Tags: sencha-touch

I need some help with carousel view logic. I want to place 12 images on one page of the carousel. 24 images at all --> 2 carousel pages.

I realy dont know how to realize that. Also want to fire an event if one of those images are tapped by the user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take a look at this tutorial there's pretty much everything you need in it if you're trying to set up an image gallery.

http://superdit.com/2011/08/20/create-image-gallery-using-sencha-touch/

Here's a demo, even though it's not convincing on a big screen :

http://demo.superdit.com/sencha-touch/gallery